# how to maintaine cookies in between two Url's in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

i need pass the cookie values to another Url which have same domain.i have two url's with same domain name..one Url for Authentication another is for retrieve data.i executed first url its authenticated . with this authentication cookie i want to execute second url ..

How to do this...i unable to Add cookie to socond url

here is my code..

string url = "http://172.16.xx.xxx:8080/cms?login&username=santhu&password=welcome";
        string url1 = "http://172.16.xx.xxx:8080//cms?status=ProcessStatus";
        string result = null;

```
    try
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
        result = client.DownloadString(url);
        TextBox1.Text = result.ToString();

        if (Response.Cookies["JSESSIONID"] != null)
            TextBox1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Response.Cookies["JSESSIONID"].Value);             

            client1.Headers.Add("JSESSIONID", TextBox1.Text);
            result = client1.DownloadString(url1);
            TextBox2.Text = result.ToString();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you may try. Define a cookie aware web client:

```
public class WebClientEx : WebClient
{
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

    public WebClientEx()
    {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

and then use this client for both requests:

```
using (var client = new WebClientEx())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "username", "santhu" },
        { "password", "welcome" },
    };
    // Authenticate
    client.UploadValues("http://172.16.xx.xxx:8080/cms?login", values);

    // Download some secure resource
    var result = client.DownloadString("http://172.16.xx.xxx:8080//cms?status=ProcessStatus");
}
```

Comment: @santhosh, if an answer was helpful to you take the habit of [marking it as such](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `cookie.Domain = "domain.com"` and it works on all url's with that domain.