# WCF URLDownloadToFile in IIS fail download

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-8

I have a WCF application that downloads a file from an external web, in development mode it works perfect, but on the IIS server it does not download the file.

```
URLDownloadToFile(0, "URLFile", HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/temp/") + "img.gif", 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

some help?

Comment: Do you see any errors?

Comment: None, just do not download, I have the try well coded and nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLDownloadToFile is part of WinInet, which is not supported under a windows service like IIS. See [INFO: WinInet Not Supported for Use in Services](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/238425/info-wininet-not-supported-for-use-in-services) for details.

Since you are using WCF, a more natural way to download files is to use the WebClient class in System.Net.

Comment: and with IIS Express in development mode if it works, but with IIS 8 not? I did it with WebClien, but since I do 2 actions, I download a captcha, extract the text and retrieve information from the same web, for some reason WebClient does not remember the first action and URLDownloadToFile, yes.

Comment: IIS Express runs in your session instead of the service session. As for captcha, my guess is that you verified with the web site manually in IE.

Comment: 137/5000
With WebClient () can I download my captcha, keep same url open and download the html to analyze it? I tried and I did not succeed.

Comment: if you can get around captcha automatically, that defeats having a captcha in the first place. with enough efforts you can solve one captcha, but the web site owner probably will switch to another since the old one no longer work.

Comment: With URLDownloadToFile, TesseractEngine; I have achieved it, I want to do the same with another alternative. in desktop mode it works, but not in the WCF server

Comment: you solved the captcha manually and saved the cookie in IE cache before calling URLDownloadToFile. In a web server 1 you don't have a human solving the captcha for every visitor and 2 WinInet is not available.

Comment: Thanks Sheng Jiang, following your advice look for more detailed information of WebClient (), and I found the solution, and now my WCF Server works perfectly, here the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502581/how-to-maintaine-cookies-in-between-two-urls-in-asp-net